# XSLT: define node id

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to output some nodes. And some of them are defined as target nodes. Some are source nodes.

Input is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Element type="node" id="Node-a" name="a"/>
<Element type="node" id="Node-b" name="b"/>
<Element type="node" id="Node-c" name="c"/>
......
```

First I tried this

```
<source node id="{generate-id()}"/>
<target node id="{generate-id()}"/>
```

It can output all of the nodes. But the problem is there are double nodes.

So I tried like this

```
<source node id="{generate-id(@source)}"/>
<target node id="{generate-id(@target)}"/>
```

However, after that I found the result could only output two nodes.

I want to ask how can I define the right node id, then I can separate them. Or should I define some variables? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What does your input look like?

Comment: Hey Phil, it likes that.

Comment: "*some of them are defined as target nodes. Some are source nodes.*" Where exactly is this definition found?

Comment: I think Phil gives the right way. In fact, I just want to get the different forms that how to describe node ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,

this is not valid:

```
<source node id="{generate-id()}"/>
```

the attribute `node` must have a value.

To answer your question, I would use the `generate-id` and `position()` functions on the `target` element to get a unique id. Something like this. Since I dont have a good input document, I created a sample:

```
<data>
    <Element type="node" id="Node-a" name="a"/>
    <Element type="node" id="Node-b" name="b"/>
    <Element type="node" id="Node-c" name="c"/>
</data>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="data">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Element">
        <xsl:element name="source">
            <xsl:attribute name="node">
                <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="target">
            <xsl:attribute name="node">
                <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(generate-id(.), '-', position())"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```